# Autoplay within HTML

Tags: javascript, video, userscripts, autoplay

I am new to Javascript... like super new :X and i am writing my very first script to try and automate video episodes of my favorite anime because the videos on the site don't have a autoplay feature after you click the link. I read about Video  and Var = 'My video' to try and figure out how to tell the script, when page loads video .autoplay = true...but i just get to dead ends. here is where i am at:

```
var urlsToLoad = [
  'http://Site1/Ep1',
  'http://Site1/Ep2',
  'http://Site1/Ep3',
  'http://Site1/Ep4'
];

if (document.readyState == "complete") {
  FireTimer ();
}

window.addEventListener ("hashchange", FireTimer,  false);

function FireTimer () {
  setTimeout (GotoNextURL, 5000); // 5000 == 5 seconds
}

function GotoNextURL () {
  var numUrls = urlsToLoad.length;
  var urlIdx = urlsToLoad.indexOf (location.href);
  urlIdx++;
  if (urlIdx >= numUrls) urlIdx = 0;
```

Once the first video link starts 'Site1/EP1', i have this going:

```
function myFunction() {
  var vid = document.getElementById("925664"); <--Ctrl+F 'Videoid' from Source 
  vid.autoplay = true;
  vid.load();
}
```

but it just stays died like 'click play to start' ..

I can really use help here PLZZZ and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [play()](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_play.asp) method instead.

```
function myFunction() {
  var vid = document.getElementById("925664");
  vid.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<!-- HTML Page -->
<video id="925664"></video>

// Javascript
function myFunction() {
    var vid = document.getElementById("925664"); // <--Ctrl+F 'Videoid' from Source 
    vid.src = "path/to/file.mp4";
    //vid.autoplay = true; // not really anything that's useful
    vid.load();
    vid.play();
}
```

Warning: Most mobile devices don't allow media files to play via code and require human interaction (click/touch) in order to start playback. However, on desktops this isn't a problem.